# Symfony 4 - Organize layout of fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Using Symfony 4, I wonder if there a simple way to organize the layout of how display my fields.

For now, I template everything in my views (to have 2 columns for example) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ form_row(form.company) }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

But, I don't want to do this, I just want to render whole form in my view, and manage the template in my `FormBuilder`. I would like to write something like :

```
$builder
    ->add('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">', HtmlType::class)
    ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Nom'
    ])
    ->add('</div><div class="col-md-6">', HtmlType::class)
    ->add('company', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Société cliente'
    ])
    ->add('</div></div>', HtmlType::class);
```

I looked at the documentation, but it's pretty poor, it shows how to inerhit from existing fields.

Is there a way to create this HtmlType to just handle simple Html tags ? or a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like that :

```
$builder->add('your_field', YourFieldClass::class, [
    'attr' => ['class' => 'your css class'],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create a custom form theme. Reference to the documentation is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html). I haven't done this myself for creating custom grid but I guess you can create some custom type options using the OptionResolver that will tell your template how to organize your fields and then based on that you can organize your custom form theme however you want.